# UIButton not work in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

After rotation of iPad in my simulator i found a strange bug - my UIButton have visible title, it property enables is YES, but, its not work. I tried to set background colour of button to black, and found that after rotation it vanish. Please take a look at portrait mode (all work):

[image]

And landscape mode (not work):

[image]

This is how i create button (i doubt that it help though, because its pretty mundane):

```
 self.readNextButton = [UIButton new];
    self.readNextButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//    self.readNextButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth  = YES;
    [self.readNextButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#60aabf"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.readNextButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    self.readNextButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:14];
    [self.readNextButton setTitle:@"Читать дальше" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:self.readNextButton];
```

Also, i want to notice that this bug appears even when i'm not rotating anything, but simply load app in landscape mode. And also, `ENABLED` property of button is 1 (mean YES), when i log it..

Button frame:

```
[self.readNextButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.right.equalTo(self.containerForNewsText.mas_right).with.offset(-10.834);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.containerForNewsText.mas_bottom).with.offset(-10.834);
        make.top.equalTo(self.truncatedNewsText.mas_bottom).with.offset(20);

    }];
```

It is in a method 'createLandscapeConstraints', that called in end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: where did u set the button frame ?

Comment: I didn't see you set the frame for `readNextButton`, could it be somewhere outside the `view`'s frame?

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai please check updated asnwer.

Comment: as you did it in `viewDidLoad`, which means the other views may not be added/initialized when you do `mas_makeConstraints:` or the frame is different form the finalized super view and end up gave you wrong result. Try move it in `viewDidAppear:` and see if it fixed the problem. If so, you have to reconsider where/when to set the constraints.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai other views declared in same method before uibutton constraints..

Comment: As the super view is not yet finalized, any subview (e.g. `containerForNewsText`)could still be in wrong position when you set the constraints. You can try use `NSLog` to print out the `readNextButton.frame.origin` once it's set and see if it's outside the super view.

Comment: Could you log the button frame in landscape mode and all its superviews? I think some view will have zero size, thus preventing the button (subviews) from getting the touch events.